# Laravel 5.1 - how to download pdf file from S3 bucket

Tags: php, laravel, pdf, amazon-s3

I am using Laravel's Storage facade and I am able to upload the pdf to S3 and I am also able to get() its contents but I cannot display or download it to the end user as an actual pdf file. It just looks like raw data. Here is the code:

```
$file = Storage::disk($storageLocation)->get($urlToPDF);
header("Content-type: application/pdf");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='file.pdf'");
echo $file;
```

How can this be done? I have checked several articles (and SO) and none of them have worked for me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think something like this will do the job in L5.2:

```
public function download($path)
{
    $fs = Storage::getDriver();
    $stream = $fs->readStream($path);
    return \Response::stream(function() use($stream) {
        fpassthru($stream);
    }, 200, [
        "Content-Type" => $fs->getMimetype($path),
        "Content-Length" => $fs->getSize($path),
        "Content-disposition" => "attachment; filename=\"" .basename($path) . "\"",
        ]);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

you can create a download url, using the getObjectUrl method

somthing like this:

```
$downloadUrl = $s3->getObjectUrl($bucketname, $file, '+5 minutes', array(
            'ResponseContentDisposition' => 'attachment; filename=$file,'Content-Type' => 'application/octet-stream',
    ));
```

and pass that url to the user. that will direct the user to an amzon page which will start the file download (the link will be valid for 5 minutes - but you can change that)

another option, is first saving that file to your server, and then let the user download the file from your server

Answer (score 4):

You can do with this code (replace with your directory and your file name) ....

Storage::disk('s3')->download('bucket-directory/filename');

Answer (score 2):

If your bucket is private, this is the way to obtain a url to download the file.

```
$disk = \Storage::disk('s3');
if ($disk->exists($file)) {
   $command = $disk->getDriver()->getAdapter()->getClient()->getCommand('GetObject', [
       'Bucket'                     => \Config::get('filesystems.disks.s3.bucket'),
       'Key'                        => $file,
       'ResponseContentDisposition' => 'attachment;'
   ]);
   $request = $disk->getDriver()->getAdapter()->getClient()->createPresignedRequest($command, '+5 minutes');
   $url = (string)$request->getUri();
   return response()->json([
       'status' => 'success',
       'url' => $url
   ]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In Laravel 5.7 it can be done with `streamDownload`:

```
        return response()->streamDownload(function() use ($attachment) {
            echo Storage::get($attachment->path);
        }, $attachment->name);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$filename = 'test.pdf';
$filePath = storage_path($filename);

$header = [
    'Content-Type' => 'application/pdf',
     'Content-Disposition' => 'inline; filename="'.$filename.'"'
];

return Response::make(file_get_contents($filePath), 200, $header);
```

Comment: Thanks for your first post. When posting code in an answer, try to avoid just posting a code block, expand your answer by offering an explanation of what you changed and why it will work. See the [community guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) for writing a good answer.

Comment: A little bit of explanation would help understand your answer better.

Answer (score 0):

```
       $d = file_full_path_here...
       $d = str_replace(' ', '%20', $d);   //remove the white space in url
       ob_end_clean();
       header("Cache-Control: public");
       header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
       header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=" . $d);              
       header("Content-Type: application/pdf");


       return readfile($d);
```

Comment: From Review:  Hi, please don't answer just with source code. Try to provide a nice description about how your solution works. See: [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Thanks

Answer (score -3):

I figured it out. Silly mistake. I had to remove the single quotes from filename.

Fix:

```
$file = Storage::disk($storageLocation)->get($urlToPDF);
header("Content-type: application/pdf");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=file.pdf");
echo $file;
```

Comment: It is a Bad solutions